# Use TV remote control on PC

Tags: windows-11, vlc-media-player, tv, ir

Is there an option to control my Win11 PC with my Sony TVs **existing remote control** (KD55XE7005).

For instance I'd like to use the `Volume +/- / Play / Stop` keys to control VLC, Windows 11 volume or KODI on that PC.

There is a similar question, but this is >10 years old: [Remote Control Adapter for PC](https://superuser.com/q/411023/72397)

I have found dozens of remote control solutions with its own remote control device + receiver, but none can be used with an existing TV remote control.

I use `Input Director` to remote control with my Laptop's mouse, and I am aware there are solutions to use my mobile phone. And, of course, any number of remote desktop solutions. But I'd like to use my TV's remote control.

Appears there is a Linux solution: https://superuser.com/a/89922/72397

Comment: You're misunderstanding your own links. Both are about PC hardware, either a standalone IR RC or TV tuners. Indeed, none can be used for your existing device.

Comment: You can logic this out: you need an receiver that will read the remote's signal, that connects to the computer, and you need software that will interpret that signal as you wish. Because most remote controls use a proprietary but known signal, it is far more common to full kits rathed than one off adapters.

Comment: Some modern remotes are actually bluetooth and might work with a PC - what the remote is might be relevant here, and if its IR you might need additional hardware

Comment: Look at https://winlirc.sourceforge.net/  (and I think this question is off topic as its a thinly disguised software/hardware recommendation)

Comment: Also https://github.com/joeuy/VLC-WinLirc-adapter

Comment: Without knowing the remote control device specifications, and perhaps the PC's specs, you can't get a useful answer.  Some remotes work by IR (light), some by radio frequencies, Some RF devices might be Bluetooth-compatible, some use WiFi, etc. It's like asking if you can toner in a printer -- that might be ink jet or impact!

Answer (score 1):

You want something called Flirc USB.  It can convert any IR received into keyboard strokes. You may need to set up shortcuts for some of what you want to do.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).